# Running Time of Graph Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, graph, big-o, vertices, edges

I am a bit confused on **how to determine the running time of graph algorithms**.  That is, determining an estimated running time using the number of vertices (n) and the number of edges (m).  Does someone mind explaining to me where my logic is flawed, and explain how to properly analyze these and find the running times?

Here is an example graph algorithm:

```
//input: Directed graph G represented by adjacency lists.
Func1(G) {
k = 0;
foreach vertex vi in V(G) do
    foreach directed edge (vi, vj) incident on vi do
    k=k+1; //just some constant time operation
    end
end
return(k);
}
```

The running time of this graph algorithm is given as O(m+n) in BigO notation.  Now here is my question:

Just looking at this algorithm for a quick mental analysis, why isn't the running time instead equal to O(n*m)?  The outer loop runs n times, in other words once for each vertex.  Now the inner loop runs once for each edge, m times.  Thus I thought that both loops together would run n*m times.

One last less trivial question is, how would the algorithm running time change should the input be given as an adjacency matrix, rather than an adjacency list?

I cannot find a good resource for this online, there are no clear and concise examples covering this topic.  Would really appreciate if someone can help me create one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It runs once for every edge incident to vi. As each edge is incident to 2 vertices, in the end, each edge is visited twice, and each vertex once. So O(n+2m) = O(n+m) using an adjacency list.

Using an adjacency matrix, to find out which edges are incident to vi, you would need O(n) operations. So the algorithm would be O(n²).

Comment: Wouldn't this mean the running time is simply 2m?  Where does the n come into play with this -- after all, there are no other operations inside of the outer loop, other than the inner loop.

Comment: No. Suppose a graph with n vertices and no edges at all. The running time would still be O(n). O(n+m) in practice means O(max(n, m)).

Comment: So what I've taken from this is, we need to think about how many times each edge/vertex are visited by the algorithm in totality.  Thank you.

Comment: @Musicode: It's generally a good idea with loops like this to count the sets of different variable bindings inside the loop and then argue that each combination of values occurs only a constant number of times. In this case, every pair of values for the variables (vi,vj) corresponds to an edge in the graph and you visit each edge only twice